# How can I visit my statements with vstmt_aux in Frama-C

Tags: c, frama-c

I am working on a plugin for scalar replacement. I have some difficulty with the statement visitor. I would like to analyze the instructions that are in loops, for each instruction I need to know if it is included in a loop, if this loop itself is included or not in another loop. Here is for example a simple example of my vstmt_aux:

```
method! vstmt_aux s = 
match s.skind with
| Loop(_, body, l, _, _) -> begin
  let lp = (fst l).Lexing.pos_lnum in 
  Format.printf "Find outer loop at line %d @.\n" lp;
  let bst = body.bstmts in List.iter(fun vbody -> 
    match vbody.skind with
    | Loop(_, subbody, lsub, _, _) -> begin
      let ls = (fst lsub).Lexing.pos_lnum in 
      Format.printf "Find inner loop at line %d @.\n" ls;
      let sub_st = subbody.bstmts in List.iter(fun ss_body ->
        match ss_body.skind with
        | Instr(ii) -> Format.printf "Find instruction %a inside inner loop. @.\n" Printer.pp_instr ii 
        | Loop(_, l_sub, lss, _, _) -> begin
          let nss = (fst lss).Lexing.pos_lnum in 
          Format.printf "Find inner inner loop at line %d @.\n" nss;
          let ss_st = l_sub.bstmts in List.iter(fun ss ->
            match ss.skind with
            | Instr(iii) -> Format.printf "Find instruction %a inner inner loop. @.\n" Printer.pp_instr iii
            | _ -> ()
          ) ss_st
        end 
        | _ -> ()
      ) sub_st;
    end
    | Instr(iloop) -> Format.printf "Find instruction %a inside outer loop. @.\n" Printer.pp_instr iloop
    | _ -> ()
  ) bst;
  Cil.SkipChildren
end
| Instr(i) -> Format.printf "Find instruction %a. @.\n" Printer.pp_instr i; Cil.SkipChildren
| _ -> Cil.DoChildren
```

And a example of code I want to analyze:

```
void test(int ni, int nj, int nk, float alpha, float *tmp, float *A) {
  int i, j, k;
  for (i = 0; i < ni; i++) 
  for (j = 0; j < nk; j++) 
    A[i * nk + j] = (float) ((i*j+1) % ni) / ni;

  for (i = 0; i < ni; i++) 
    for (j = 0; j < nj; j++) {
      tmp[i * nj + j] = 0.0;
      for (k = 0; k < nk; ++k) 
        tmp[i * nj + j] += alpha * A[i * nk + k] * A[i * nk + k];
    }
}
```

When I run this script on this c code, only instruction `A[i * nk + j] = (float) ((i*j+1) % ni) / ni;` is detected.

> Find instruction *(A + (i * nk + j)) = (float)((i * j + 1) % ni) / (float)ni; inside inner loop.

When I use `DoChildren` instead of `SkipChildren` in Loop pattern case, all instructions inside loops are detected more than one time. For example:

- instruction `A[i * nk + j] = (float) ((i*j+1) % ni) / ni;` is detected three times:

> Find instruction *(A + (i * nk + j)) = (float)((i * j + 1) % ni) / (float)ni; inside inner loop.
>
> Find instruction *(A + (i * nk + j)) = (float)((i * j + 1) % ni) / (float)ni; inside outer loop.
>
> Find instruction *(A + (i * nk + j)) = (float)((i * j + 1) % ni) / (float)ni;.

where only the first message is true.

- instruction `tmp[i * nj + j] = 0.0;` is detected one time but output message is not correct (while this instruction is inside an inner loop)

> Find instruction *(tmp + (i * nj + j)) = (float)0.0;.

- same thing happens for instruction `tmp[i * nj + j] += alpha * A[i * nk + k] * B[k * nj + j];`.

When I add braces around instructions of each loop plus DoChildren, all instructions are detected by the pattern `| Instr(i) -> Format.printf "Find instruction %a. @.\n" Printer.pp_instr i; Cil.SkipChildren`.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the easiest answer is to show the code of `Kernel_function.find_enclosing_loop`, that returns the innermost loop to which a given statement belong (and raise `Not_found` if said statement is not in any loop). Note that for mainly historical reasons, the original code inherits from `Cil.nopCilVisitor`, but this does not matter here, and `Visitor.frama_c_inplace` should be preferred unless you have very specific uses.

```ml
let find_enclosing_loop kf stmt =
  let module Res = struct exception Found of Cil_types.stmt end in
  let vis = object
    inherit Visitor.frama_c_inplace
    val loops = Stack.create ()
    method! vstmt_aux s =
      match s.skind with
        | Loop _ ->
          Stack.push s loops;
          Cil.DoChildrenPost (fun s -> ignore (Stack.pop loops); s)
        | _ when Cil_datatype.Stmt.equal s stmt ->
          raise (Res.Found (Stack.top loops))
        | _ -> Cil.DoChildren
  end
  in
  try
    (match stmt.skind with
      | Loop _ -> stmt
      | _ ->
        ignore
          (Visitor.visitFramacFunction vis (get_definition kf));
        raise Not_found)
  with
    | No_Definition -> raise Not_found (* Not the good kf obviously. *)
    | Stack.Empty -> raise Not_found (* statement outside of a loop *)
    | Res.Found s -> s
```

Basically, the idea is that you maintain a stack of currently visited loops, and each time you reach a statement of interest, you can check how many elements there are in the stack. When you're done visiting the children of a loop, you just have to pop the stack (hence the `DoChildrenPost`).